# How to define css selector class prefix with SASS

Tags: css, class, sass, selector

Is there any posible to write this construction?

```
[class^="name"]{ 
   &[class*="-1"]{
       padding: 10px;
   }
}
```

To have this solution

```
.name-1
```

but only for this type of class prefix.

For example if i write:

```
<span class="name-1"></span>
```

this will be work, but when i write

```
<span class="othervalue-1"></span>
```

there will be nothing to show.

Comment: And what you wrote does not work? What CSS does it generate?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following construct:

```
[class^="name"]{ 
   &[class$="-1"]{
       padding: 10px;
   }
}
```

For reference check out the [W3C Selectors section](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).

**EDIT**

[CSS Version on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZKAe/1/)

As Beterraba mentioned this will also match `.nameother-1`. To avoid this use the following:

```
[class|="name"]{ 
   &[class$="-1"]{
       padding: 10px;
   }
}
```

If you e.g. want to match `.name-1-2` you could do the following:

```
[class|="name"]{ 
   color: red;

   &[class*="-1"]{
       padding: 10px;
       color: green;

       &[class$="-2"]{
           padding: 30px;
           color: yellow;
       }  

   } 
}
```

But this would also match `.name-15-2`. To avoid that you need to make something like this:

```
[class|="name"]{ 
    color: red;

   &[class$="-1"]{
       padding: 10px;
       color: green;
   } 

   &[class$="-1-2"]{
       padding: 30px;
       color: yellow;
   }     
}
```

But this would also match `name-5-1-2`. And so on.. I think the list is endless.
Anyway it's getting very unreadable. I don't recommend you to do so. Why not simply targeting these elements directly?

Comment: ok, but if i have also other option like `&[class$="-2"]` and class costruction will be `.name-1-2` or `.name-2-1` ?

Comment: It will match `nameother-1`

Comment: this not change anything :(

Comment: @Lukas Which class do you want to target? `.name-1-2`?

Comment: yes i need to get class `.name-1-2` or `.name-2-1` but if i write `.othername-1-2` this will works only for first type of combination

Comment: @Lukas Have you used `[class|="name"]` at the beginning? With that `.othername-1-2` won't match.

Comment: OK, i try to use some mixin for class sytnax and the problem comes when i set my clasess with it, so: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZKAe/2/ the output is the same but resoult...

Comment: @Lukas I don't get what you exactly want.. Why do you pass `othername` to the mixin when you don't want to use it? http://jsfiddle.net/9ZKAe/3/ Please clarify what you exactly want, otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: My intend is combination of classes which is always depended on their prefix... if you are inside the combination of the same values ​​with one another it will not overlap because they will be distinguished prefix. So if i do this i have this tipical problem http://jsfiddle.net/9ZKAe/4/ :(

Answer (score 4):

With Sass you can use variables and use them inside the selector. This way you can use your prefix as a variable and nest the suffixes you want to select.

Let's say your prefix is `name`, and the suffix you want to select is `-1`, but you don't want to select `othername-1`. You can do the following:

```
$prefix: name
.#{$prefix}
    &-1
        padding: 10px

    &-other_selected_suffix
        color: green
```

This code would select both `name-1` and `name-other_selected_suffix`, but it will not select `othername-1`